# VSCode flutter hot reload

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, hot-reload

When I enter `flutter run` into the terminal, everything is fine and my app runs on my iOS emulator.
However, it opens a new line `MacBook-Pro:testApp mattk$`, and if I press `r` and hit enter, it returns `-bash: r: command not found`.

If I "start without debugging" through VisualStudio Code, it gets stuck on "running Xcode build" and the app is blank on my emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are run app using terminal with `flutter run` and everything is fine then cursor can not goto new line and it can not show `MacBook-Pro:testApp mattk$`, but terminal shows like: [image]